# not able to run protractor test from eclipse on chrome browser

Tags: eclipse, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

not able to run protractor test from eclipse on chrome browser but if I change browser to firefox test runs fine.

```
      exports.config = {

allScriptsTimeout : 60000,

suites : {

    LoginTestSuite: 'e2e/TestSuites/Full/LoginTestSuite/*.js',
},    
 capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' },
 directConnect : true,      
baseUrl : 'http://test:8080/',

framework : 'jasmine2',

jasmineNodeOpts : {
    defaultTimeoutInterval : 60000
},
onPrepare : function() {        
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
        var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
        var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll : true,
            savePath : 'tests/test-results',
            filePrefix : browserName + '-xmloutput',
            modifySuiteName : function(generatedSuiteName, suite) {
                return browserName + '.' + generatedSuiteName;
            }
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);

        var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

        var today = new Date(),
        year = today.getFullYear(),
         month = today.getMonth() + 1,
         date = today.getDate(),      
         hh = today.getHours(),
         min = today.getMinutes(),
         timeStamp = year +''+ month+'' + date+'' + hh + min;

        var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({               
            cleanDestination: false,
            showSummary: true,
            showConfiguration: true,
            showQuickLinks: true,                
            reportTitle: "E2E Report--Test run on" + timeStamp,               
            dest : 'tests/test-results/screenshots',
            filename : 'my-report-'+ timeStamp + '.html',
            captureOnlyFailedSpecs : true,
            pathBuilder : function(currentSpec, suites, browserCapabilities) {

                return browserCapabilities.get('browserName')+'-' +timeStamp + '/' + currentSpec.fullName;
            }
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    });
},
resultJsonOutputFile : 'tests/test-results/output.json'
};
```

I have tried updating protractor version to 4.0.11 and this uses chrome driver version : 2.25 if I run it from eclipse I get following error :

```
  E/launcher - session not created exception
  from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"8084.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
```

If I run my test from command `npm run e2e-full` my test will run in `chrome` browser but running it from `eclipse` give error.

Also If I change browser type to `firefox` in config file and run it from `eclipse` test will run fine.

Not sure what could be the issue only running from `eclipse` in `chrome` browser gives this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar issues when I updated my version of Google Chrome.  I believe it's a bug in protractor.

I was able to fix this by reinstalling protractor and chrome driver.  My respective versions:

```
Protractor: 4.0.9
Chromedriver: 2.24
```

Comment: I upgraded used following versions and it worked :   `Protractor: 4.0.10
Chromedriver: 2.25`